# Problems with Tornado Web Server

Tags: python, webserver, tornado

I am using OSX 10.58 with the following versions:

```
curl --version
curl 7.16.4 (i386-apple-darwin9.0) libcurl/7.21.0 OpenSSL/0.9.7l zlib/1.2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz 

Using /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg
Processing dependencies for setuptools
Finished processing dependencies for setuptools
Searching for pycurl==7.16.2.1
Best match: pycurl 7.16.2.1
Processing pycurl-7.16.2.1-py2.5-macosx-10.5-i386.egg
pycurl 7.16.2.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/pycurl-7.16.2.1-py2.5-macosx-10.5-i386.egg
Processing dependencies for pycurl==7.16.2.1
Finished processing dependencies for pycurl==7.16.2.1
Searching for simplejson
Best match: simplejson 2.1.1
Processing simplejson-2.1.1-py2.5-macosx-10.5-i386.egg
simplejson 2.1.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/simplejson-2.1.1-py2.5-macosx-10.5-i386.egg
Processing dependencies for simplejson
Finished processing dependencies for simplejson
```

I installed tornado and the only demo that seems to work is helloworld. The rest of the demos hang when I provide my Google authentication credentials. I am thinking it might have to do with my pycurl/curl versions, because it took me a long while to get those to compile and build. I am hoping there is not a mismatch.

Thanks
- Joe

Here is an example of the output I am seeing from the Python process running the demo:

```
./demos/auth/authdemo.py 

[I 100728 14:20:39 web:824] 302 GET / (127.0.0.1) 1.41ms
[I 100728 14:20:39 web:824] 302 GET /auth/login?next=%2F (127.0.0.1) 0.81ms
[I 100728 14:20:40 httpclient:498] GET https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud?openid.op_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fud&openid.sig=1cEG6lxPr87e6hcOmTge%2BhM7Yvk%3D&openid.ext1.type.email=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2Fcontact%2Femail&openid.ext1.value.firstname=firstname&openid.response_nonce=2010-07-28T18%3A20%3A40ZWatqZPv83GqxXg&openid.ext1.mode=fetch_response&openid.ext1.type.lastname=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2FnamePerson%2Flast&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Fauth%2Flogin&openid.ext1.value.language=en-US&openid.claimed_id=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawnuikv4sbZBpYTPyZHhtozdE1H8u44OzTM&openid.ns.ext1=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fsrv%2Fax%2F1.0&openid.signed=op_endpoint%2Cclaimed_id%2Cidentity%2Creturn_to%2Cresponse_nonce%2Cassoc_handle%2Cns.ext1%2Cext1.mode%2Cext1.type.firstname%2Cext1.value.firstname%2Cext1.type.email%2Cext1.value.email%2Cext1.type.language%2Cext1.value.language%2Cext1.type.lastname%2Cext1.value.lastname&openid.ext1.value.lastname=mylastname&openid.ext1.value.email=myname%40gmail.com&openid.assoc_handle=AOQobUdxlHZ0vMhEpSLIS5MbkynzadEc7XuFx4IOl5kN2sq3SeWvpVIc&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=check_authentication&openid.identity=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawnuikv4sbZBpYTPyZHhtozdE1H8u44OzTM&openid.ext1.type.firstname=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2FnamePerson%2Ffirst&openid.ext1.type.language=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2Fpref%2Flanguage
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use Python 2.5, just try to use the 2.6-2.7 version of Python, it should help.

Quote from Tornado prerequisites:

> On Python 2.6 and 2.7, there are no dependencies outside the Python
>   standard library, although PycURL (version 7.18.2 or higher required;
>   version 7.21.1 or higher recommended) may be used if desired.
>
> On Python 2.5, PycURL is required, along with simplejson and the
>   Python development headers (typically obtained by installing a package
>   named something like python-dev from your operating system).